# Action Bar not showing in android application for GingerBread and above versions

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-2.3-gingerbread

I am developing an android app for the versions gingerbread and above and i wanted to add action bar in the app but after completing all the necessary code it is not showing up. I have created the xml file for the actionbar layout,added menu in the onOptionsItemSelected Method() and also defined its actions in the onOptionsItemSelected() method.

**XML File**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


   <item
        android:id="@+id/home_button"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:title="@string/action_first"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        />
    <item 
        android:id="@+id/about"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:title="@string/action_second"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        />

</menu>
```

**onCreateOptionsMenu() and onOptionsItemSelected()**

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.play__bani, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        switch(item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.home_button:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Home button pressed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;
        case R.id.about:
            Toast.makeText(this, "About button pressed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

**minSdkVersion and targetedSdkVersion declaration**

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
```

Please tell me where i am wrong and what should i need to do!!

Comment: What is the theme that you have in your manifest file ? It might be a one with no title bar. Please select a theme which does not say ".No Title Bar"... Its worth a try.

Comment: Have you included requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE) in your code ?

Comment: No Title Bar theme is not appearing in the manifesto file

Comment: where should i include the requestWindowFeature() ?

Comment: You should not include it, that will be included if you dont want your title bar to appear. Have you tried clicking on the default menu button in your device or emulator ?

Answer (score 0):

**According to the [Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html)**

> Beginning with Android 3.0 (API level 11), the action bar appears at
>   the top of an activity's window when the activity uses the system's
>   Holo theme (or one of its descendant themes), which is the default.
>   You may otherwise add the action bar by calling
>   requestFeature(FEATURE_ACTION_BAR) or by declaring it in a custom
>   theme with the windowActionBar property.

The ActionBar has been introduced in Android Version 3.0 so you can't magically use a (for Gingerbread) non-existing UI element in your app. You need to include some kind of support-library.

You can use [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com), a great external library. Or google's own ActionBarCompat (include the support library in you v7 SDK)